# make object follow each other

Tags: lua, coronasdk

By using this code I can move the 'magnet' on the Y axis but how can I link the 'field' to the 'magnet' so when I move the 'magnet' the 'field' moves with it?

```
magX = 300
magY = 100 

field = display.newImageRect( "field.png", 330, 330 ) ; field.alpha = 0.2
field.name = "field"
field.x = magX; field.y = magY
physics.addBody( field, "static", { isSensor=true, radius=180, filter=fieldFilter } )

magnet = display.newImageRect( "magnet.png", 128, 128 )
magnet.name = "magnet"
magnet.x = magX ; magnet.y = magY
physics.addBody( magnet, "static", { bounce=0, radius=40, filter=magnetFilter } )


function magnet:touch( event )
    Runtime:removeEventListener( "touch", screenTouch )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        self.markX = self.x    -- store x location of object
        self.markY = self.y    -- store y location of object
    elseif event.phase == "moved" then
        local x = moverX --(event.x - event.xStart) + self.markX
        local y = (event.y - event.yStart) + self.markY
        self.x, self.y = x, y    
        if self.y > 500 then self.y = 500 end       
        if self.y < 100 then self.y = 100 end 
        magX = self.x
        magY = self.y
    else
    Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", screenTouch )
    end
    return true
end
magnet:addEventListener( "touch", magnet )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by adding **transition.to( field, { time=1, x=self.x, y=self.y } )** to the  **elseif event.phase == "moved" then**

```
function magnet:touch( event )
    Runtime:removeEventListener( "touch", screenTouch )
    if event.phase == "began" then

        self.markX = self.x    -- store x location of object
        self.markY = self.y    -- store y location of object

    elseif event.phase == "moved" then

        local x = moverX --(event.x - event.xStart) + self.markX
        local y = (event.y - event.yStart) + self.markY

        self.x, self.y = x, y    -- move object based on calculations above
        --print("touch")

        if self.y > 500 then self.y = 500 end       
        if self.y < 100 then self.y = 100 end 

        magX = self.x
        magY = self.y

        transition.to( field, { time=1, x=self.x, y=self.y } )

    else
    Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", screenTouch )
    end
    return true
end
```